# AJAX jQuery PHP Return Value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to AJAX and am kind of confused by what PHP passes back to the jQuery.
So you have an AJAX function like this:

```
 $.ajax({ url: '/my/site',
     data: {action: 'test'},
     type: 'post',
     success: function(output) {
                  alert(output);
              }
 });
```

(I took this from ajax another StackOverflow page.)

But on various other resources they will have the success section look like this:

```
 success: function(data) {functionfoocommandshere}
```

I am just confused as to what dictates the naming of this variable? If the PHP ultimately echoes an array:

```
  echo $myVar;
```

How can I get this from the AJAX?

Comment: The `data` variable of the `success` method will hold anything you `echo` in PHP. You can not pass an array directly; you have to convert it to JSON first.

Comment: Which variable are you confused about the naming of?

Comment: See this http://www.php4every1.com/tutorials/jquery-ajax-tutorial/

Comment: The variable that contains the returning php information. So it just doesn't matter? the .ajax command will know that anything within the function () arguments is returning php information?

Comment: Also: you can'y `echo` an array in PHP, you can `print_r` or `var_dump` or `serialize` it, but `echo` is meant for strings or ints, etc.

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as it is a valid variable name.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An Ajax-Requests fetches a whole site. So you'll not get any data in variables, but the whole site in the data-parameter. All echos you made together will be in this parameter. If you want to retrieve an array, you should transform it to json before.

```
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

Then you can receive it via Ajax in this way

```
$.ajax({ url: '/my/site',
 data: {action: 'test'},
 dataType: 'json',
 type: 'post',
 success: function(output) {
              alert(output);
          }
 });
```

Comment: Do you really need to `echo` the value?  what about if you don't want to show the `output`? @Gnietschow

Comment: `echo` does not show anything to the user it only writes data in the response of the server, so it is sent to the client. After the ajax call received the `output`, It is up to you whether you show this response to the user or not.

Answer (score 7):

In you PHP file, use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to turn the array into a more convenient format for use in Javascript. So you would have something like:

```
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

Then, in your JavaScript, the `data` variable of the `success` method will hold the JSON. Use jQuery's [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to convert this to a JavaScript object, which will then be very easy to manipulate. I don't know what you array contains, but you might do something like this:

```
$.ajax({ url: '/my/site',
    data: {action: 'test'},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert(obj.name[0] === "John");
      }
});
```

Again, the `data` variable here will contain anything your PHP outputs, but JSON is a common and convenient way to transfer data back to your JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: '/my/site',
    data: {action: 'test'},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(output) {
        alert(output);
    }
 });
</script>

<?php
$action = $_POST['action'];
echo $action;?>
```

Any output that is printed/echoed will be returned to the success function. This is handy when you want to fill an html container with something that you need to run in real time.

Once you get the hang of this, another option is to use JSON to return variables with values.

Comment: its retrieving the complete html formate, i want to return only the value

Answer (score -1):

The data that's returned from the PHP AJAX function, can be retrieved from the `success` block. Here's the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
 $.ajax({ url: '/my/site',
 data: {action: 'test'},
 type: 'post',
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(output) {
     //output is the data returned from PHP AJAX function in JSON format
     alert(output); 
   }
 });
```

Comment: So it just doesn't matter? the .ajax command will know that anything within the function () arguments is returning php information?

Comment: It's not a matter of "knowing", it's part of the description of .ajax: the success function receives the returned data as an argument.

Comment: -1  You're not automatically guaranteed that your ajax call will know that passed JSON is actually json.....and Jquery isn't dealing with PHP, it's dealing with data (remember, PHP is interpreted before it outputs to screen, where JQuery has access to the data)  By default, it'll try its best guess, which isn't guaranteed to be JSON.  That's why best practice is to define the dataType (could be json, text, jsonp, html, etc) and then to expect that as the return in the success function.