# Post some field values using ajax before submitting from submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Can I post some values using ajax before submitting fields from submit button ?

I'm using the following code. It reaches success but I'm not able to get the posted data.
Any clue for this ?
Your help/review will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
function auto_fill(){  

        var that = $(this),
            url = './auto_fill.php',
            type = that.attr('method'),
            data = {};

        that.find('[name]').each(function(index,value){
            var that =$(this),
                name =that.attr('name'),
                value = that.val();
                data[name] = value;
        }); 

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                        document.getElementById("f_name").value="<?php echo $name ?>";
                        document.getElementById("phn_no").value="<?php echo $phn_num ?>";

            }
        });

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: echo $name will only work on first page load, you should use the response you are getting to set the value

Comment: What response returns server script?

Comment: How is `auto_fill` called?

Comment: @juvian I used `if(isset($_POST['id_num'])){
    $name = Sam;
}` in auto_fill.php then include it in my form.php where this form include.

Comment: Is this what are you trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366204/ajax-jquery-php-return-value

Comment: @juvian no, the problem is `$_POST['id_num']` Is not happening

Comment: why continue the submit if you use ajax?

Comment: @Andrei by using something like this, `<input name="Id_num" onblur="auto_fill()" value="">`

Comment: data[name] = value; Are you sure name='id_num'?

Comment: @dandavis Because I need to auto fill some field after I enter Id number, then need to submit whole values. Do you know a link that will have this kind of example

Comment: why not try to get a json encoded response as the link I posted ? Also try to set $name to a default value to check if $_POST['id_num'] is not working, and console.log(response) in your ajax success function

Comment: @A.Wolff I used `if(isset($_POST['id_num'])){     $name = Sam; $phn_num= 07139439493 }` in auto_fill.php then include it in my form.php where this form and jscript included too.

Comment: @juvian Good idea, Thanks,  I need to auto fill some field after I enter Id number, then need to submit whole values. Do you know any link that will have this kind of example.

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm using `<form method="post" name="myform" id="myform" action="auto_fill.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: @Pras could you post value of `data` passed to request? I mean, just before request what gives you `console.log(data);` ? BTW, here `that` won't be what you seem to expect it to be (FORM), but the window object

Comment: @A.Wolff this was the out put onblur `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
function auto_fill(){
  $.getJSON("./auto_fill.php?id_num=" + $("#id_num").val(),
        function(data){
          $.each(data, function(i,item){
            if (item.field == "first_name") {
              $("#f_name").val(item.value);
            } else if (item.field == "phonenum") {
              $("#phn_no").val(item.value); 
            } 
          });
        });
}
```

### auto_fill.php

```
$id = $_GET['id_num'];

//build the JSON array for return
$json = array(array('field' => 'first_name', 
                    'value' => 'Your name'),

              array('field' => 'phonenumber', 
                    'value' => $phn),
              array('field' => 'somethinglikeDiscription', 
                    'value' => 'You entered ID as '.$id));
echo json_encode($json );
```

you can pass any variable to this values by this JSON array.