# Ajax change icon color add/remove wishlist

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Example :

If user has already added product A in wishlist heart icon should be display in red color, And If user click on add to wishlist button it will remove product A from  wishlist and heart icon should be display in grey color.

```
<a class='addtowishlist' href='javascript:;' data-data='".$row['p_id']."'><i class='fa fa-heart'></i> Add to Wish list</a>
```

---

**ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".addtowishlist").live('click', function(evt) {
       var link_data = $(this).data('data');
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'addtowishlist.php',
          data: ({product_id: link_data}),
          success: function(data) {
          }   
       });   
    }); 
});
</script>
```

**addtowishlist.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['product_id'])) {  
    $addmemberid = $_SESSION['member_id'];
    $addproductid = $_POST['product_id'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(w_p_id) cnt FROM wishlist WHERE w_m_id = '$addmemberid' AND w_p_id = '$addproductid'") or die(mysql_error());
    $countid = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if($countid['cnt'] == 1){
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM wishlist WHERE w_p_id = '$addproductid' AND w_m_id = '$addmemberid'") or die(mysql_error()); // If product has already added to wishlist then remove from Database
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO wishlist SET w_p_id = '$addproductid', w_m_id = '$addmemberid'") or die(mysql_error()); // If product has not in wishlist then add to Database
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Add a return value to your php code. Check this return value in the ajax success function. Then depending on this value set the color of your heart

Comment: @M.G Hi, Do you have any example? I don't understand how it's work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to your heart icon.

```
<i class='fa fa-heart whishstate'>
```

Change your addtowishlist.php to something like that:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['product_id'])) {  
    $addmemberid = $_SESSION['member_id'];
    $addproductid = $_POST['product_id'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(w_p_id) cnt FROM wishlist WHERE w_m_id = '$addmemberid' AND w_p_id = '$addproductid'") or die(mysql_error());
    $countid = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if($countid['cnt'] == 1){
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM wishlist WHERE w_p_id = '$addproductid' AND w_m_id = '$addmemberid'") or die(mysql_error()); // If product has already added to wishlist then remove from Database
        echo '0';
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO wishlist SET w_p_id = '$addproductid', w_m_id = '$addmemberid'") or die(mysql_error()); // If product has not in wishlist then add to Database
         echo '1';
    }
}
?>
```

Then in change your ajax call to something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".addtowishlist").live('click', function(evt) {
       var link_data = $(this).data('data');
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'addtowishlist.php',
          data: ({product_id: link_data}),
          success: function(data) {
               if(data == '1')
               {
                  $('a[data-data="' + link_data + '"] > i.whishstate').css({"color":"red"})
               }
               else{
                   $('a[data-data="' + link_data + '"] > i.whishstate').css({"color":"red"})
               }
          }   
       });   
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: It change all heart color in same page, How do I fix that to change only product that I've clicked?

Comment: Thank you so much, Do you have any article about send/return value between PHP to Ajax? I need to learn more for it.

Comment: Look at here, there is a solution with returning json to ajax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366204/ajax-jquery-php-return-value

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Mark my answer as solution if i could help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104975/discussion-between-vintage-beef-and-m-g).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".addtowishlist").live('click', function(evt) {
```

Change this to

```
$(".addtowishlist").on('click', function(evt) {
```